# Avoid duplicate code in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Is there any way to remove this duplicate code?

```
ldbShow.css({
    'left': 'auto',
    'top': 'auto'
})
ldbForum.css({
    'left': 'auto',
    'top': 'auto'
})
```

I was thinking about something like this:

```
(ldbForum, ldbShow).css({
    'left': 'auto',
    'top': 'auto'
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/) method

> Create a new jQuery object with elements added to the set of matched elements.

```
ldbForum.add(ldbShow).css({
'left': 'auto',
'top': 'auto'
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a style as an object and reuse it.

```
var css = { 'left': 'auto', 'top': 'auto' };
ldbShow.css(css);
ldbForum.css(css);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `add()` method to join two or more jQuery objects together:

```
ldbShow.add(ldbForum).css({
    'left': 'auto',
    'top': 'auto'
});
```

Note that a better solution all together would be to use a common class on all the elements and then select them in a single jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

use `.add()` method:

```
ldbShow.add(ldbForum).css({
    'left': 'auto',
    'top': 'auto'
})
```